# Pull to refresh on Ionic algolia instant search

Tags: angular, algolia, ionic4

I implemented an [Angular Algolia Instant Search](https://community.algolia.com/angular-instantsearch/) on Ionic 4 and wanted to use the ion refresher to a new list of items. Is it possible to update a certain div element? for example, update the `ng-template` again?

I already tried `location.reload()` but I don't want to reload the whole page.

This is on my HTML:

```
      <ais-hits>
        <ng-template let-hits="hits">
          <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
            <ion-refresher-content
              pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
              pullingText="Pull to refresh"
              refreshingSpinner="circles"
              refreshingText="Refreshing..."
            >
            </ion-refresher-content>
          </ion-refresher>

          <div *ngFor="let item of hits">
            <ion-card (click)="displayItem(item)">
              <ion-item>
                <ion-label>{{ item.name}}</ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-card>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ais-hits>
```

On my Ts:

```
  doRefresh(event) {
    location.reload();
    event.target.complete();
  }
```

On Pull to Refresh, I want to update the list of content. But it doesn't refresh the content.